# OS X - Deciding between anaconda and homebrew Python environments

Tags: python, macos, numpy, homebrew, anaconda

I use Python extensively on my Mac OS X, for both numerical applications and web development (roughly equally). I checked the number of Python installations I had on my laptop recently, and was shocked to find **four**:

```
Came with Mac OS X:
/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin

Installed via Homebrew
/usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:05:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin

Installed via Anaconda/Miniconda
~/anaconda/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

Came with the downloaded .pkg from python.org
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
```

I decided to unify all of this, and use `conda`. I removed the Homebrew version and the Python.org download (kept the main system one). Conda is great for numerical computing, because I can install Jupyter/Numpy/Pandas in the root environment, and not have to bother install virtualenvs for every project.

But now my entire web development workflow is messed up. None of my virtualenvs work, since apparently one's not supposed to use conda and virtualenv together. I tried to create conda environments from the `requirements.txt` file. One package I was using with django was "markdown_deux", which is not available in the Conda repo. I looked at ways of building it, but creating a recipe takes a lot of effort (create YAML file, etc..)

Has anyone found a good compromise for this? I'm thinking of going back to the homebrew version for general use, and writing an alias for changing the path back to the conda version as necessary. Though this will also require tracking which one I'm using now..

Comment: May I ask how did you find out there were four? What's the command you used to find those python distributions?

Comment: You can try something like this in Mac or Linux: `locate python | grep "bin/python"`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I use Homebrew Python for all my projects (data science, some web dev).

Conda is nothing fancy, you can have the same packages by hand with a combination of `pip` and [Homebrew science](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science). Actually, it is even better because you have more control on what you install.

You can use your virtualenvs only when you do web development. For the numerical applications you will probably want to have the latest versions of your packages at all times.

If you want to update all your packages at once with pip, you can use this command:

```
sudo -H pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 sudo -H pip install -U
```

EDIT: This answer is old, if you want a more up-to-date comparison, I found this nice blog article which compares the two approaches:

https://towardsdatascience.com/pipenv-vs-conda-for-data-scientists-b9a372faf9d9

I still use Homebrew Python, and pip / pipenv over conda.

Comment: What do you mean by "You can use your virtualenvs only when you do web development."? I use it for scikit-learn, that works fine.

Comment: @henrikstroem I meant that you only need to really use virtualenvs when you need a specific version of your packages as you would do for a webapp. For science you probably want to use the latest packages because they are compatible

Comment: Why would you have more control using homebrew and pip compared to using conda?

Comment: Conda comes with more than 300 packages. I doubt all are useful for one's domain of expertise. Another point is that brew packages requires brew python. It is a pain to change it to anaconda (I tried).

Comment: @Kikohs I've installed both and only use homebrew python because some apps need it to install but i like anaconda, the package dependencies tool is great at figuring out compatible versions, homebrew is very lacking.  i'd to find a way to force homebrew to recognize anaconda python and those packages instead of having duplicate.

Comment: I disagree. I'm "doing science" and I need to have both python2 and python3 at the same time, to be compatible with different people. I love conda's solution (which I am using on my office computer), and am yet to have found a proper way to handle the different iPython versions on my Mac OS computer with homebrew.

Comment: I totally agree with you, Anaconda is nothing but a pip + virtualenv (+ virtualenvwrapper). However recently I have discovered one limit to the built-in Python (which is not "because of" Python): some libraries can only be installed on Anaconda, and not with Python. My example is Gurobi (a linear optimizer).

Comment: Homebrew science is deprecated. This question and answer needs updating -- the whole issue of installing Python on Mac has changed. Caveat Emptor!

Comment: What's the/a new way we're supposed to use now @stonecanyon ?

Comment: Conda is different that pip. Pip can only install python package but conda can install other kind of package.

Comment: Conda is absolutely not just pip + virtualenv. If you believe this, you really need to do some deeper digging into what conda actually does.

Comment: @PMende The answer is 6 years old.. Conda changed :)

Comment: @Kirell Sorry, should have tagged who I was speaking to. Was directed at one of the comments. Anyway, I think it's important context for people who come here: conda is a full-blown environment solver, and handles non-Python dependencies. Both of these capabilities are missing from pip/venv.

Answer (score 22):

Workflow that I've found the best:

- Use `conda` for virtual environment management. **Never** use / install into system python.
- Use `pip` to install into the active virtual environment, just like normal.
- Use `conda` packages *only* for hard to install software, such as Qt.

Automation / extras

- Use `autoenv` or `direnv` and automatically activate virtual environments when you enter a directory by putting the conda command inside the `.env` or `.envsrc` file.