# Best Practices with Anaconda and Brew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, anaconda

I have just got a new Macbook with OSX Sierra, so want to ensure my development environment is setup properly.

I am looking to follow the 'best practices' mentioned here: https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup

I need Python 2.x for work (urllib, Pandas, Numpy, Scikit-learn), and Python 3.x for some online classes (Pandas, Numpy, Django) I am taking. 
I have installed Python 2 and 3, using `brew install python` and `brew install python3` respectively.

However, on this link, there is no mention of Anaconda, just IPython. 
Given that I already have Python 2 and 3 installed via Homebrew, is it even advisable to use anaconda, or should I stick to standard IPython as mentioned on the Github link above? 
I am confused after reading this post: [OS X - Deciding between anaconda and homebrew Python environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541876/os-x-deciding-between-anaconda-and-homebrew-python-environments)

If Brew and Anaconda can indeed work together, what specific steps can I take to ensure that there are no conflicts between the two versions?

Comment: Homebrew cask.... `brew cask install anaconda`

Comment: @cricket_007 That command freezes with 'PREFIX=/usr/local/anaconda3

Comment: @shuhalo Okay, well, I typically use `pyenv`  instead of Homebrew for my Python

Comment: @shuhalo it doesn't provide any updates for a while after that output, but it does not freeze on my machine.

Comment: I feel that @cricket_007 's appoach is the right approach, but: (a) it should be written as an answer, not just a comment, and (b) it should have more *details*, like *why* it is best to first install homebrew, then install conda *via* homebrew.  I am not convinced this is the best way, even though I feel it is.  The reasoning behind this method would be helpful, especially in terms of how it impacts your `$PATH` variable and where Anaconda and Python are stored.

Comment: Update: New homebrew syntax:  `brew install --cask anaconda`

Answer (score 23):

`brew` and `conda` tend not to play nicely together, but I think I have a set up that has worked quite well for me so far. It was inspired by [this post](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/keep-anaconda-from-constricting-your-homebrew-installs).

You can add the following code to your `.zshrc`:

```
# Deactivates conda before running brew. 
# Re-activates conda if it was active upon completion.

brew() {
    local conda_env="$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV"
    while [ "$CONDA_SHLVL" -gt 0  ]; do
        conda deactivate
    done
    command brew $@
    local brew_status=$?
    [ -n "${conda_env:+x}" ] && conda activate "$conda_env"
    return "$brew_status"
}
```

You want to deactivate `conda` before running `brew` so that `brew` doesn't find `conda` packages in your `PATH` whenever it tries to install something. In fact, `brew doctor` will complain if you have not deactivated `conda` before running brew, as mentioned in the post I link to above. (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975533/how-to-resolve-potential-conflicts-due-to-anaconda-and-homebrew).)

One thing I should mention is that `conda` environments "stack", but the `brew()` function I've written above does not keep track of your stack of environments. (See below for a version of this function that keeps track of this.) For example, if you do `conda activate newenv` while a `conda` environment `oldenv` is active, then `conda deactivate` will return you to `oldenv`. However, if you run `brew` using the function I've written above after activating `oldenv` and then `newenv`, running `conda deactivate` will not return you to `oldenv` but will deactivate your conda environments entirely.

This function also probably creates some unnecessary overhead when running `brew`, as I believe you only really need to deactivate your `conda` environment when running `brew install`. That said, if you're the kind of person to care about that overhead enough, this answer probably doesn't tell you anything you didn't already know.

As a final note, `brew cask install anaconda` does not strike me as a good idea, since `conda` was designed to be installed in `$HOME`, but `brew cask` will want to install it in `/usr/local`, so that could lead to unpredictable behaviour.

**Edit:** Here's is a version of the `brew` function which leaves your conda environments as it found it:

```
brew() {
    local -a conda_envs
    while [ "$CONDA_SHLVL" -gt 0  ]; do
        conda_envs=("$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV" $conda_envs)
        conda deactivate
    done
    command brew $@
    local brew_status=$?
    for env in $conda_envs; do
        conda activate "$env"
    done
    unset env
    return "$brew_status"
}
```

I've tested this in Zsh. I don't think it will work in Bash. If you want to use it in Bash, you will need to change the for loop declaration to say something like `for env in ${conda_envs[@]}`. I haven't tested this, however, so please test that it does what you need before use.

Comment: Would putting the entire body of the function inside a subshell (parenthesis pair) work for brew to function properly AND to "reactivate" (by exiting subshell) conda?

Comment: @Mark Apologies, I haven’t been on SE in a while so I only just saw your comment. That may work, I’m not sure. Have you tested it out? One way to see is to try it with `brew doctor`, which will complain if it finds another version of Python in your PATH. As an aside, I think this function can be easily modified to keep track of your conda environment stack if you’re using Zsh.

Comment: @Mark I've updated my answer with something you may be related to your question.

Comment: FYI, the parens method seems to work in bash, just make `{`->`{(`, `}`->`)}` and remove `[ -n "${conda_env:+x}" ] && conda activate "$conda_env"` from original

Answer (score 3):

I am new to python, and have had trouble with my python installation. I have both python installation from homebrew and anaconda on my mac. My anaconda installation had messed up my homebrew python dependency for vim and MacVim.

My solution is whenever I am installing/update package via homebrew I would remove anaconda from my PATH. This is a bit of a pain, but I only installing/updating package via homebrew once in a while so it okay.

To switch between python 2 and 3 here are my commands in Terminal:

```
$ conda search python
...
...
$ conda install python=3.5.0

$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
py27                     /Users/apollotang/opt/local/anaconda2/envs/py27
py36                     /Users/apollotang/opt/local/anaconda2/envs/py36
root                  *  /Users/apollotang/opt/local/anaconda2

$ source activate py36      ### <——— here is the command in to change python version 
(py36) $ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
py27                     /Users/apollotang/opt/local/anaconda2/envs/py27
py36                  *  /Users/apollotang/opt/local/anaconda2/envs/py36
root                     /Users/apollotang/opt/local/anaconda2

(py36) $ python -V
Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
```

I found this command from 
[How to change default Anaconda python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment)
and 
http://chris35wills.github.io/conda_python_version/

Also, here is a very good article on best practice on setting up python environment on mac
https://www.davidculley.com/installing-python-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a virtual environment (virtualenv) and assign different versions Python to each so there wouldn't be any overlap causing dependency issues.

Check out 'The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python' on how to walk through the setup.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 2):

Installing `anaconda` would mean you have no need of the system Python (leave it to the system, since you probably don't want to change it), or of Pythons installed by `homebrew`.

When you create a `conda` environment you can specify which version of Python you want it to use. For example:

```
$ conda create --name myenv python=3.5
```

Activating a `conda` environment (after the above command you'd do this with `conda activate myenv`, or `source activate myenv` for earlier versions) automatically means that the `python` command will run the Python interpreter you selected for that environment. Packages can be installed with `pip` as well as `conda install`, and are pretty much compatible with `conda` environments.

Answer (score 1):

If using **.bash**, the following will ***temporarily*** deactivate anaconda environment while running brew command(s). (see original zsh [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62179041/10951593))

###### Step 1

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

--add--

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

###### Step 2

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

--add--

```
# Temporarily deactivates anaconda environment to run brew command(s)

brew() {(
    local conda_env="$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV"
    while [ "$CONDA_SHLVL" -gt 0  ]; do
        conda deactivate
    done
    command brew $@
    local brew_status=$?
    return "$brew_status"
)}
```