# How to install Anaconda without messing with default environment (MacOS)?

Tags: python, anaconda, zsh

I have to to install Anaconda. I already have Python3, Python2, pip, pip3, HomeBrew, etc. My concern with installing Anaconda is that it'll mess with all my default settings. I don't want to change anything in my default environment. I'm using zsh and ohmyZsh as my terminal. I did a little research on installing Anaconda and saw to prevent Anaconda from being using as default, you delete the export path from .bashrc. Is there anything else I need to do to prevent conflicting problems? Is there a way to use Anaconda without overriding the current setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Practices with Anaconda and Brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859781/best-practices-with-anaconda-and-brew)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the inclusion of the Anaconda folders in the PATH. Just make sure you don't add them to PATH or remove them after installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command will run conda from any terminal without having base environment activated by default.

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

This will only work if you have done `conda init`(works for version > 4.16.12 and later) after installation.

If you want a terminal to have base environment activated by default then just set `auto_activate_base` to `True`

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base True
```

Hope, this answer will help you.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same setup. Follow the anaconda [install instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) and don't worry. Deleting the `EXPORT PATH` should be enough.

If you want to use `conda` inside your zsh (which you probably do) you will need to do a [`conda init`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370467/anaconda-not-found-in-zsh) (check second answer), which will add some lines in your `.bash_profile` (which is sourced inside `.zshsrc`).

And do check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859781/best-practices-with-anaconda-and-brew) as commented by [Adam Kern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12104492/adam-kern).